Blender adds addional bones on export (disable add leaf bones/better fbx export addon dont help)
Blender adds addional bones on export (disable add leaf bones/better fbx export addon dont help)
After export
Before 
Project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aJrQEQrzYd_8Ev-3uzxya3XAsVniAABm/view?usp=drive_link
